# Connection management is working off line Message

Tags: oracle, ssis, connection, offline, connector

I've got this question. Yesterday I was working in my SSIS project without any problem. In one of the task I have created a connection to one Oracle database. Everything was working perfect. Just to clarify, the project is hosted in a PC that is never switch off because there are some scheduled tasks that run very late at night.

But today, when I tried to run the package again I've get the following message:

**Connection Management 'name' is working off line.**

I tried to test the connection again but I could get any answer from the Oracle database. However from other PC's there is no problem with this connection.

What could be happening? or, what else is necessary to do in order to keep the connection working?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the connection manager and uncheck the option of "Work offline" or something of that sort.